# How to run SQL queries on RDS Oracle DB through Ansible Playbook

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-rds, ansible-inventory

I have a requirement at work to run some SQL Queries on RDS DB remotely. These are currently done manually and I have decided to automate this.

Can someone help me how to do it and provide sample code/reference links.

Right now I have below open questions.

**1. How provide AWS credentials to Ansible Playbooks? Is it done through module variables or environment variables?**

**2. How to pass AWS IAM Role to Ansible Playbook?**

**3. How can I inject the SQL Scripts in the ansible playbook?**

**4. What will the inventory.yaml file look like?**

**5. How can I take care of SQL run failures and recovery?**

Any help would be considered grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: did you achieve what you are looking for ? 
i am also trying to achieve the same